# Cannot find -lSDLmain -lSDL.dll

Tags: c

I'm trying to setup the 1.2.13 version of SDL library (windows:CodeBlocks),I've started an SDL project and I copied the file "SDL.dll" In my project folder, so everything is supposed to be fine, but after the compilation the error "cannot find -lSDLmain ..." is beeing displayed ( the joined image )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of CodeBlocks?

The same thing happened to me in the latest version of CodeBlocks (20.03). You should install the CodeBlocks 17.02 release, which worked fine for me.
See if that works for you.

[Here is the link for Codeblocks 17.02.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/17.12/Windows/)